# Excel Linear Interpolation VBA

Tags: vba, excel, interpolation, linear-interpolation

this function interpolates/extrapolates a table of known x,y
For example,

```
x y
1 10
2 15
3 20
```

Linterp(A1:B3, -1) = 0

However, this code can only do two adjacent arrays.
I would like to modify this code so that I can
select two separate arrays, for example N106:N109,P106:P109.
How can I make this adjustment in this code?

```
Function Linterp(r As Range, x As Double) As Double
     ' linear interpolator / extrapolator
     ' R is a two-column range containing known x, known y
    Dim lR As Long, l1 As Long, l2 As Long
    Dim nR As Long
     'If x = 1.5 Then Stop

    nR = r.Rows.Count
    If nR < 2 Then Exit Function

    If x < r(1, 1) Then ' x < xmin, extrapolate
        l1 = 1: l2 = 2: GoTo Interp

    ElseIf x > r(nR, 1) Then ' x > xmax, extrapolate
        l1 = nR - 1: l2 = nR: GoTo Interp

    Else
         ' a binary search would be better here
        For lR = 1 To nR
            If r(lR, 1) = x Then ' x is exact from table
                Linterp = r(lR, 2)
                Exit Function

            ElseIf r(lR, 1) > x Then ' x is between tabulated values, interpolate
                l1 = lR: l2 = lR - 1: GoTo Interp

            End If
        Next
    End If

Interp:
    Linterp = r(l1, 2) _
    + (r(l2, 2) - r(l1, 2)) _
    * (x - r(l1, 1)) _
    / (r(l2, 1) - r(l1, 1))

End Function
```

Comment: If a discontinuous range is passed you can detect that using `r.Areas.Count`

Comment: Sorry but I am new to VBA. what does r.Areas.Count do exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

one very simple way is having the function accepting two ranges in input, one for X values (say rX) and one for Y ones (say rY), and then changing every occurrence of `r(foo,1)` to `rX(foo)` and `r(foo,2)` to `rY(foo)`

like follows

```
Option Explicit

Function Linterp2(rX As Range, rY As Range, x As Double) As Double
     ' linear interpolator / extrapolator
     ' R is a two-column range containing known x, known y
    Dim lR As Long, l1 As Long, l2 As Long
    Dim nR As Long
     'If x = 1.5 Then Stop

    nR = rX.Rows.Count
    If nR < 2 Then Exit Function

    If x < rX(1) Then ' x < xmin, extrapolate
        l1 = 1: l2 = 2: GoTo Interp

    ElseIf x > rX(nR) Then ' x > xmax, extrapolate
        l1 = nR - 1: l2 = nR: GoTo Interp

    Else
         ' a binary search would be better here
        For lR = 1 To nR
            If rX(lR) = x Then ' x is exact from table
                Linterp2 = rY(lR)
                Exit Function

            ElseIf rX(lR) > x Then ' x is between tabulated values, interpolate
                l1 = lR: l2 = lR - 1: GoTo Interp

            End If
        Next
    End If

Interp:
    Linterp2 = rY(l1) _
    + (rY(l2) - rY(l1)) _
    * (x - rX(l1)) _
    / (rX(l2) - rX(l1))

End Function
```

but you must implement code to check for consistency of the two ranges, like being both of one column each and with the same number of rows

Comment: FYI, this function requires the x-range (xR) to be sorted smallest to largest

Answer (score 0):

use this function  :

```
Public Function lineare_iterpolation(x As Variant, x1 As Variant, x2 As Variant, y1 As Variant, y2 As Variant) As Variant
    If x = x1 Then
        lineare_iterpolation = y1
        Exit Function
    End If
    If x = x2 Then
        lineare_iterpolation = y2
        Exit Function
    End If
    lineare_iterpolation = y1 + (x - x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
    Exit Function
End Function
```